# How to preserve exit code when ending ssh session with a DigitalOcean droplet?

Tags: bash, ssh, digital-ocean

I have a DigitalOcean droplet `mydroplet` that I'm accessing remotely via a bash script with the DigitalOcean CLI [`doctl`](https://github.com/digitalocean/doctl). When the ssh connection terminates, I need to access the exit code of the last command that ran on the droplet, i.e. `$?`. However, DigitalOcean seems to aggregate all ssh exit codes >0 to 1. Is there a way I can preserve the original exit code?

For example:

```
>> doctl compute ssh mydroplet --ssh-command "exit 12"
>> echo $?
1 # how can I make this 12?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know nothing about `doctl` but as a workaround you can do like this:

```
doctl compute ssh mydroplet --ssh-command 'rc=12; echo DOCTL_EXIT=$rc; exit $rc'
```

The you can parse the `doctl`'s output and get the exit code you want.